# Android - Make a background image not stretch it's assigned view out

Tags: android, background, tablelayout, stretch

Hooray for pictures!  Here's what it looks like when assigning the picture to the background, and when not.

[image]

[image]

I'd very much like for it to not stretch out the top `TableView` if the image is larger than the table.  I've included an empty "view" to give a little bit of extra space for the table's background already as well, as you can see in the XML to follow.  Tried to mess around with ScaleType, but that was a wash.

How can I get the BG to stretch to fit the layout?  I'm trying to handle the "user xxx has a smaller screen than WVGA" gracefully.  I lack grace, apparently.

```
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/widget29"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:background="@drawable/minetownx480"
>
<View
android:id="@+id/blankSpace"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="60dip" />

<TableRow android:id="@+id/widget40" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/moneyText" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Money: $$$$$$$$$" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:id="@+id/savingsText"  android:gravity="right"  android:text="Savings: $$$$$$$"  android:layout_weight="3" android:textSize="12sp"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/widget41" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/wagonText" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Wagon Space: XXX/XXX" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/loanText" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Loans: $$$$$$$$" android:gravity="right" android:layout_weight="3" android:textSize="12sp"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/widget42" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/daysText" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Days Left: XX/XX" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/armedText" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Unarmed!" android:gravity="right" android:layout_weight="3" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The tablelayout is the first element of the root linearLayout, if that matters at all.

Edit:  Alternatively, if you know how I could measure the tableLayout's X and Y space before assigning the image, I could scale it programmatically before assigning it....  Either solution would be good if anyone knows!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use FrameLayout and create two layers (i.e. add two views inside). First would be an ImageView and the second, therefore the top one, would be your table. In this way I would not rely on the table to control my image scaling but it would be independent from the ImageView which one can then hopefully more easily manipulate as it is not showing the image as 'background' but as the source.

Comment: Excellent.  I implemented it using this and it is working.  I was completely unaware of how frameLayout worked, this was a great explanation.