# Using an Android Spinner

Tags: android-spinner

I'm new to Android and Java. I want to create an application with one spinner. I want it to: select an element form the spinner, for example element1, and I want it to show in a text view case, a definite text.

```
Spinner id: `Spinner_Elemente`
Spinner Items: String Array: `Elemente`
Text View id: edtElemente
```

Can you help me with some simple code? I looked on the [developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)  but I don't understand it. So, I would be grateful if you can help me with an simple code for my example.

sorry for my eng. :)

Comment: If your question is solved, you should post an answer and accept it instead of putting *solved* into your title

Comment: @j0k, ok thanks (i'm new on stackoverflow) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED, @Rishi,there was a little problem in the code.... The corect code

```
public class ChimExpressMainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
Spinner Spinner_Elemente_Java;
TextView Text_Despre_Element_Afisare;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chim_express_main);
    Spinner_Elemente_Java=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner_Elemente);
    Spinner_Elemente_Java.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    Text_Despre_Element_Afisare=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.edtElement);
    Text_Despre_Element_Afisare.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_chim_express_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
////////////////////////----TEST SPINNEER----////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Text_Despre_Element_Afisare.setText((CharSequence) Spinner_Elemente_Java.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
        //Text_Despre_Element_Afisare.setText("Hidrogenul este elementul chimic în tabelul periodic al elementelor cu simbolul H și numărul atomic 1. Este un gaz ușor inflamabil, incolor, insipid, inodor, iar în natură se întâlnește mai ales sub formă de moleculă diatomică, H2. Având masa atomică egală cu 1,00794 u.a.m. , hidrogenul este cel mai ușor element chimic. Etimologic, cuvântul hidrogen este o combinație a două cuvinte grecești, având semnificația de „a face apă”.Hidrogenul elementar este principala componentă a Universului, având o pondere de 75 % din masa acestuia.[1] În starea de plasmă, se găsește ca element majoritar în alcătuirea stelelor. Hidrogenul elementar este foarte puțin răspândit pe Pământ.Pentru necesități industriale există diferite procedee de fabricație, puse la punct din punct de vedere tehnologic sau aflate în fază de laborator. Hidrogenul poate fi obținut prin electroliza apei, procesul necesitând costuri mai mari decât cel de producere prin procesarea gazelor naturale.[2]Cel mai răspândit izotop al hidrogenului este protiul, care este alcătuit dintr-un singur proton în nucleu și un electron în învelișul electronic. În compușii ionici poate avea sarcină negativă (anion cunoscut sub numele de hidrură, H-) sau sarcină pozitivă H+ (cation). Hidrogenul formează compuși chimici cu majoritatea elementelor din sistemul periodic și este prezent în apă și în mulți dintre compușii organici. Are un rol important în reacțiile acido-bazice, acestea bazându-se pe schimbul de protoni între molecule. Fiind singurul atom pentru care soluția analitică a ecuației lui Schrödinger este pe deplin cunoscută, prezintă un rol major în fundamentarea teoriei mecanicii cuantice.Hidrogenul este un gaz puternic reactiv și își găsește aplicații datorită capacității sale chimice de reducător.[3] Hidrogenul se folosește în industria petrochimică la producerea benzinelor, în industria chimico-alimentară pentru hidrogenarea grăsimilor (de exemplu producerea margarinei), în prelucrările mecanice ale metalelor și în tratamentul termic al acestora.[4]Hidrogenul reprezintă o alternativă pentru înlocuirea benzinei drept combustibil pentru vehiculele echipate cu motoare cu ardere internă.[5] Avantajele sale principale constau în faptul că este ecologic, din arderea sa rezultând vapori de apă, iar randamentul termic al motoarelor cu hidrogen este ridicat. Dezavantajele constau în pericolul mare de explozie, dificultatea stocării în vehicul și lipsa unor rețele de stații de alimentare cu hidrogen. Una dintre cele mai promițătoare soluții tehnice o reprezintă conversia directă a energiei chimice din hidrogen în electricitate, prin intermediul pilelor de combustie.[6]");
        //Text_Despre_Element_Afisare.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    

    if(arg0.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Hidrogen")){
        Text_Despre_Element_Afisare.setText((CharSequence) Spinner_Elemente_Java.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
    }
    else{
        if(arg0.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Heliu"))
        {
            Text_Despre_Element_Afisare.setText((CharSequence) Spinner_Elemente_Java.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
        }
        else{
            Text_Despre_Element_Afisare.setText("Close");
        }
    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are certain steps to be followed for Spinner to work

1. Create an array in res/values/array.xml or strings.xml
   e.g.

   ```
   <resources>
       <string-array name="colors">
           <item>Red</item>
           <item>Green</item>
           <item>Blue</item>
           <item>White</item>
       </string-array>
   </resources>
   ```
2. Create a Spinner element in main layout file
   e.g.

   ```
   <Spinner
   android:id="@+id/spin"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:entries="@array/colors"
   android:prompt="@string/SPrompt"/>
   ```
3. Implement OnItemSelectedListener interface in java activity
4. Create java object:
   e.g.

   Spinner s=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);
   s.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
5. Override two methods and do the work you want when something is selected from the spinner:

   ```
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){}
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){}
   ```

Comment: i know steps 1,2,4, but i don't understand steps 3 and 5, can you apply those steps on my example tu understand it? (please)

Answer (score 0):

This is the suggested java file for your example.

```
public class SpinnerExActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
Spinner s;
TextView tv;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    s=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner_Elemente);
    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.edtElemente);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
{
    tv.setText(s.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
{
}
```

}

Comment: two more questions :)
1) What are arg0, 1, 2 and 3?
2) Can you help me to set the layout for my HTC Sensation device? I have to create the resolution because i can't find it in Eclipse. I have only for Nexus One and other devices bot not for HTC Sensation and i didn't find on the web something to help me :)

Comment: ok, so i know all the `arg`, but if i want from an object from the spinner for example `element1` to show `aaaaa` end for `element2` to show `ccc` how i do it? I no want it to show what i had selected in the Spinner :)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html this link will help you to understand the objects arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3. and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859547/layout-issue-on-htc-sensation this might help you for the layout of HTC Sensation.

Comment: ok, but how do i compare arg2 with an char for example `char hidrogen = "Hidrogen"`

Comment: so i have to compare the selected item from the spinner with an char, but how can i do it? :|